# Is it possible to create an intermediate image within docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

Imagine two docker compose services whose images have the following `RUN` steps:

```
FROM base
RUN step1
RUN step2
```

and

```
FROM base
RUN step1
RUN step3
```

Assume each step is somewhat lengthy.

The naive approach, having two `Dockerfile`s as above is suboptimal (as step1 is executed twice during the initial `docker-compose up`) and not DRY (step1 is repeated twice, specially bad if step1 is quite convoluted)

The other approach I see, manually creating an `intermediate` image:

```
FROM base
RUN step1
```

which is then used with these two `Dockerfile`s:

```
FROM intermediate
RUN step2

FROM intermediate
RUN step3
```

is suboptimal, as a `docker-compose up` will no longer work out of the box, since it will require users to first manually create this intermediate image.

Is there anyway to do this entirely within `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is step one? If it's truly the same if will be cached by the daemon and reused. There is no setting for compose to 'pre-build' an image for later use. It's considered outside the scope of compose - https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/1547#issuecomment-112254616.

Comment: This is kind of the answer. Didn't realize that docker would reuse a cache that was created while building another image. step1 could be any set of steps that are considered slow to run and that you want to avoid re-running. Pretty building wasn't part of the requirements, since the image is not intended to be used outside of compose.

Comment: Don't know where 'pretty' came from haha, meant 'pre-build'. Ye you can get some great benefits from the cache if you're sensible about how you structure your Dockerfiles.